# How many samples should be taken to capture the mean and variance of the original set with given error?

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics, distribution, sample

I have a set ***S*** of N real numbers. I wanna calculate the mean ***m*** variance ***v*** of ***S***. But since N is too large, I do not want to use all of the numbers. Instead, I would like to sample *n* numbers uniformly randomly from the N-number set ***S***, such that mean and variance of the sampled set does not deviate too much from the original set. Say, the error I can tolerate is *em*, and *ev* respectively (which means that the mean of the sample set should fall in (1+-*em*)***m***, and the sample variance should fall in (1+-*ev*)***v***). How large should *n* be?

Comment: belongs to [statistics.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I will post it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite this having nothing to do with programming, I'll give you a hint where to find it:

The mean distribution of a sampled populations follows a **Student Distribution**.

The variance distribution of a sampled population follows a **Chi-Squared Distribution**.

That only applies if your set S is normally distributed. If that's the case, search for *Student's t-test* and *chi-squared test*.

But this is statistics, not programming.